# How to use Backbone for simple animations?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 3 simple animations in my web application where I do not hit the server and do not need to save the page state.

They are a simple drop down menu, a page flipper, and a pane flipper, which is basically a small page with in the page.

Can I model these in Backbone.  Rather, should I model these in backbone?

Here is an example of my page flipper:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
*/
    var Page = $A.Class.create('public', {
        Name: 'Page',

        // (P)roperties
        P: {
            page_previous:  null,
            head_previous:  null
        },

        // (Css) Classes
        C: {
            visible:        'inline',
            invisible:      'none'
        },

        // (E)lements
        E: {

            // body types
            body_splash:     '#body_splash',
            body_main:       '#body_main',
            body_settings:   '#body_settings',

            // heading types
            heading_splash:  '#heading_splash',
            heading_main:    '#heading_main'
        },

        // main, splash, settings
        flip : function (input) {
            var page_current,
                head_current;

            if (!input) {
                input = 'splash';
            }
            if (input === 'main') {
                $A.Event.trigger('main_flipped');
            }

            // set page and header based on input - update this later
            page_current =  this.E['body_' + input];

            if (input === 'settings') {
                head_current =  this.E.heading_main;
            } else {
                head_current = this.E['heading_' + input];
            }

            $A(page_current).fade();
            head_current.style.display = 'inline';

            // Turn off previous page / header
            if (this.P.page_previous !== null && this.P.page_previous !== page_current) {
                this.P.page_previous.style.display = 'none';
            }
            if (this.P.head_previous !== null && this.P.head_previous !== head_current) {
                this.P.head_previous.style.display = 'none';
            }

            // Update previous page / header
            this.P.page_previous = page_current;
            this.P.head_previous = head_current;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by model?

Comment: you can just use animations like you normally would. ie. on render: `$('.yourView').fadeIn()`.

Comment: There is some logic associated with the animations.  I posted a page flipper class above.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish these kind of things by using backbone.[marionette](http://marionettejs.com/). In this [github repo](https://github.com/Puppets/marionette-cookbook) you can find some examples of dropdown menus and page flippers.

Comment: where is the api, the links you gave are pretty general.